# Programmable Control of USB Device

Tags: c#, usb, lpt

I have used the LPT port before with a VB6 library called `inpout32.dll`. I'm much more familiar with that but it is not used in modern computers, such as laptops.

I need to control a device with on / off capabilities. This would have been very easy with LPT, but I need to work with USB and C# in this case. There are some USB2LPT cables out there on the market, but I read that they can't be programmed the same way.

Has anyone used those cables before? If yes, how can I work with them. Otherwise what are my alternatives?

Comment: Just FYI you don't need to sign your posts.

Comment: [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/)